# DbSet<TEntity>, IQueryable<TEntity> - OOP concepts

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop, iqueryable, dbset

```
public interface IDepartmentDataSource
{
    IQueryable<Department> Departments { get; }
}

public class DepartmentDb : DbContext, IDepartmentDataSource 
{
    //Error: property cannot implement property.... 
    public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; } 


    //should be: 
    //public IQueryable<Department> Departments { get; set; }
}
```

*(Used code from Pluralsight)*

From MSDN:

```
public class DbSet<TEntity> : DbQuery<TEntity>, 
IDbSet<TEntity>, IQueryable<TEntity>, IEnumerable<TEntity>, 
IQueryable, IEnumerable 
where TEntity : class
```

Why do I have to specifically implement as IQueryable ?

Answer (score 1):

```
public class DepartmentDb : DbContext, IDepartmentDataSource
{
    public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }

    IQueryable<Department> IDepartmentDataSource.Departments
    {
        get { return Departments; }
    }
}
```

You should explicitly set your `DbSet` from the interface class `IDepartmentDataSource`.

Comment: Doesn't explain why you have to explicitly do this, but it is the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class DepartmentDb : DbContext, IDepartmentDataSource 
{
    //Error: property cannot implement property.... 
    public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; } 
}

public class MyQueryable<T> : IQueryable<T> {}

....

MyDepartmentDb.Departments = new MyQueryable<Department>(); // Error!
// but it implements IDepartmentDataSource
// which should let any IQueryable<Department> in, so what gives??
```

Because the code above wouldn't work, but should. i.e. you should be able to assign any `IQueryable<Department>` to the `Departments` property, not just a `DbSet<Department>`.